# Gconf-editor missing gnome-system-tools from tree

Tags: gnome, configuration, gconf, configuration-management

I am trying to to enable the /apps/gnome-system-tools/users/show_all flag that is supposed to be in gconf-editor.

According to the Ubuntu community documentation, and many google searches, the key I want should be in the above location but the entire /apps/gnome-system-tools tree is missing.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FixShowAllUsers

My problem is not getting the key to work, I will deal with that later, I do not have /apps/gnome-system-tools in the tree view.

Some users claim that it shows if you run gconf-editor as root, but mine is exactly the same running as root.

Based upon what I have read here:
http://projects.gnome.org/gconf//

I think that the hive/config-source was never added when the gnome-system-tools package was built into the release. Either that or they have moved the branch and I have yet to find the documentation noting the move.

It looks like I could start adding folders in {$HOME}/.gconf/apps/ and they would then show in the tree, but I would prefer to have everything from the gnome-system-tools branch loaded in properly.

Also from what I can tell there is no good way to start adding folders to the tree view directly via the gconf-editor tool, right click does nothing and there are no preferences under Edit.

How do I get the /apps/gnome-system-tools branch to appear in gconf? Or, if necessary, where do I find its default configuration source so that I may add it?

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal i386 version, with Gnome version 2.32.1, and the 2.32.0-0ubuntu7 gnome-system-tools package is installed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

gnome-system-tools now uses *dconf* instead of *gconf* so you have to use `dconf-editor` (not installed by default, install package `dconf-tools`) instead of `gconf-editor`.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... Thanks, this was exactly the answer. I should think the dconf package should be made a dependency of gnome-system-tools or at least be one of the suggested add-ons in Ubuntu Software Center. Or at least installed by default.

Comment: The answer is confusing because the package name to install is `dconf-editor` and not `dconf-tools`. So `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` guys!